Checkboxes update in desktop/web client fails
I have an app which a message is updated that contains several blocks that have checkboxes with initial options. Slack desktop/web client only correctly updates the first checkbox in each block, while it leaves the others unchecked. If the user interacts with the checkboxes in a block then from that time on it correctly updates the checkboxes. The mobile version works correctly, so I guess this is a Slack desktop/web client issue.
The message payload is checked and it correctly has the initial options in the checkboxes, however the Slack desktop/web client does not show the marks on the boxes.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
